# Adding a Paragraph to Woocommerce Intro Email

Tags: php, email, woocommerce

I'm working to learn php but don't have time before a required change needs to be made.

I've attached an image of the current welcome email that Woocommmerce sends to new vendors. I would like to add a paragraph (including a url) directly after (with a space between) the line that says "Thanks for creating your account on..."

The new line would say something along the lines of "For Seller resources, click here (with link to a page)."

[image]

Here is the current code in the php email template from Wooocommerce that I will override.

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
exit; // Exit if accessed directly
```

}

?>

```
<p><?php printf( __( 'Thanks for creating an account on %1$s. Your username is %2$s.', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $blogname ), '<strong>' . esc_html( $user_login ) . '</strong>' ); ?></p>
```

```
<p><?php printf( __( 'Your password has been automatically generated: %s', 'woocommerce' ), '<strong>' . esc_html( $user_pass ) . '</strong>' ); ?></p>
```

```
<p><?php printf( __( 'You can access your account area to view your orders and change your password here: %s.', 'woocommerce' ), make_clickable( esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) ) ); ?></p>
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line below the first printf.

```
<p><?php printf( __( 'For Seller resources, click <a href="%s">here</a>.', 'woocommerce' ), 'http://yoururlhere.com' ); ?></p
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! If I just wanted to add a simple line (no link) how would I do this? Just removing the link in what you provided gives me an error.

Comment: And thanks so much - been wanting to cross this off for a while!

Comment: You can simply skip the printf() statement and use an echo statement like so:

     `<?php echo "<p>Your simple text line here</p>" ?>`